# iOS memory leaks. CFString and Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, instruments, cfstring

When I run my game made with unity with the xCode at the beginning it looks ok (main menu + intro). But when I load the first level the memory usage grows until 300MB (just 40MB when I load it on the Unity editor).
Using Instruments, in the Allocations Summary, I can see that CFString is absorbing all my memory. The responsible library is one called Foundation.
I'm not able to understand what it means. So, I am really far from a solution.
Help, please. What can I do?

Comment: How do you know that you have a memory leak, and not just huge memory requirements?

Comment: What I know is that is not a problem of textures and that I don't use complex data structures. How do I know? well, I don't know it at all. But any help will be ok.

Comment: Try turning things off in your game until you find where the problem is.